# Locker Service Blocking Access to Third-Party Object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, locker-service

I'm running into a scenario where I can't tell if Locker is preventing accessing an API call from a third-party script that's been whitelisted.

I'm using Qualtrics survey tool to poll users on our Salesforce Community site. Qualtrics provides a `<script>` to their API that I've added to the Community head which generates the survey pop-up when the page loads. I've whitelisted `https://*.qualtrics.com` under CSP Trusted Sites.

Because we're building single-page apps in Salesforce Lightning, the [Qualtrics documentation](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/website-app-feedback/common-use-cases/single-page-application/) suggests manually loading the JavaScript API by calling the Qualtrics `QSI` object.

My component calls `doInit`:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller.js calls `loadQualtrics`:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    try {
        helper.loadQualtrics(component, event, helper);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

My Helper.js is using an eventListener on `loadQualtrics` to determine when the `QSI` object is ready...

```
loadQualtrics: function(component, event, helper) {
    window.addEventListener("qsi_js_loaded", helper.interceptLoaded(component, event, helper), false);
}
```

...and if `QSI` is ready, the `interceptLoaded` function in Helper.js runs the methods in the `QSI` object:

```
interceptLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
    QSI.API.unload();
    QSI.API.load();
    QSI.API.run();
}
```

When I run this in my scratch org I get `ReferenceError: QSI is not defined`. If I create a static HTML page on my dekstop with the Qualtrics `<script>` in the head and add some basic functions in plain JavaScript, I can access the `QSI` object. Is Locker service preventing me from accessing?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm experiencing the same problem. From what I can tell and from what I've researched, Salesforce is blocking access to the global namespace so you're not able to access the QSI object (which exists globally) from within the Aura component. I'm not sure of a way around it.

Comment: @Eric I didn't get it figured out completely. Had to add an event listener in the community head to wait for the object to load. But had to set a timeout because doInit would load before the QSI object was ready.
 `({
    loadQualtricsAPI : function(component, event, helper) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("loadQualtricsAPI event...");
            let siteIntercept = new Event("loadSiteIntercept");
            window.dispatchEvent(siteIntercept);
            console.log("loadQualtricsAPI event complete");
        }, 3000);
    }`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to set **Script Security Level** of your Community Builder to **Allow Inline Scripts and Script Access to Whitelisted Third-party Hosts**

> [Content Security Policy Restrictions in Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_security_csp.htm)
>   Strict CSP tightens CSP to mitigate the risk of cross-site scripting
>   attacks by disallowing the **unsafe-inline** and **unsafe-eval** keywords for
>   inline scripts (**script-src**). Ensure that your code and the third-party
>   libraries that you use adhere to these rules by removing all calls
>   using **eval()** or inline JavaScript code execution. Consider updating
>   your third-party libraries to modern versions that don’t depend on
>   **unsafe-inline** or **unsafe-eval**.

Comment: Oleh -- I tried that and Locker is appending `data-locker-src` to the script: <script data-locker-src="/core/resources/assets/myJsFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>